# Unexpected Results using fts_children() in C

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, system-calls, traversal

I have been beating my head on a wall over this fts_children() question.  In the man page, http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fts.3.html, it clearly states `As a special case, if fts_read() has not yet been called for a hierarchy,
       fts_children() will return a pointer to the files in the logical directory
       specified to fts_open(), that is, the arguments specified to fts_open().` 
Which I take to mean that a linked list of all the files in the current directory are returned.  Well, I am finding that not to be the case and I would really appreciate some help in the matter.  I expected a linked list to be returned and then I would iterate through it to find the file with the matching file name (the end goal).  However, right now, I am just trying to iterate through the linked list (baby steps).  Right now, it will return one file and then exit the loop.  This does not make sense to me.  Any help would very much appreciated!!!

Opening of file system:

```
char* const path[PATH_MAX] = {directory_name(argv[argc-index]), NULL}; 
            char* name = file_name(argv[argc-index]);

            if ((file_system = fts_open(path, FTS_COMFOLLOW, NULL)) == NULL){
                fprintf(stderr,"%s:%s\n", strerror(errno), getprogname());
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                 }/*Ends the files system check if statement*/

            /*Displays the information about the specified file.*/
            file_ls(file_system,name, flags);
```

For clarification, the directory_name parses the inputted path from the user and returns something like /home/tpar44.  That directory is then opened.

Searching within the file system:

```
void
file_ls(FTS* file_system, char* file_name,  int* flags){
    FTSENT* parent = NULL;
    //dint stop = 0;

    parent = fts_children(file_system, 0);

    while( parent != NULL ){
        printf("parent = %s\n", parent->fts_name);
        parent = parent->fts_link;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `char* const path[PATH_MAX] = {directory_name(argv[argc-index]), NULL};` - that's an array of PATH_MAX c-style strings, but filled with only 2 entries, the second NULL?

Comment: @sehe its actually a 2D array isn't it? I had to make the filesystem variable of fts_open a char* const* so this is how i did it.  Its terrible i know but I had no idea how to work with it.  Also, the second argument is NULL to prevent iterating past the end.

Comment: it is not too bad, but the use of PATH_MAX shows confusion. Better yet, you can leave it out, since the initializer will allow the compiler to deduce the array size. (I have posted an answer showing this, among other things)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is entirely by design.

> ...that is, the arguments specified to fts_open()...

What it says is that it will list the root elements in the `path_argv` parameters for your convenenience. It treats the `path_argv` array as a *logical directory* itself.

In other words this:

```
int main(int argc, char* const argv[])
{
    char* const path[] = { ".", "/home", "more/root/paths", NULL }; 

    FTS* file_system = fts_open(path, FTS_COMFOLLOW | FTS_NOCHDIR, &compare);

    if (file_system)
    {
        file_ls(file_system, "", 0);
        fts_close(file_system);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Will output

```
parent = .
parent = /home
parent = more/root/paths
```

Which, in fact, it does (see http://liveworkspace.org/code/c2d794117eae2d8af1166ccd620d29eb).

Here is a more complete sample that shows complete directory traversal:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fts.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>

int compare (const FTSENT**, const FTSENT**);

void file_ls(FTS* file_system, const char* file_name, int* flags)
{
    FTSENT* node = fts_children(file_system, 0);

    if (errno != 0)
        perror("fts_children");

    while (node != NULL)
    {
        // TODO use file_name and flags
        printf("found: %s%s\n", node->fts_path, node->fts_name);
        node = node->fts_link;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* const argv[])
{
    FTS* file_system = NULL;
    FTSENT* node = NULL;

    if (argc<2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <path-spec>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(255);
    }

    char* const path[] = { argv[1], NULL }; 
    const char* name = "some_name";

    file_system = fts_open(path, FTS_COMFOLLOW | FTS_NOCHDIR, &compare);

    if (file_system)
    {
        file_ls(file_system, name, 0); // shows roots

        while( (node = fts_read(file_system)) != NULL)
            file_ls(file_system, name, 0); // shows child elements

        fts_close(file_system);
    }
    return 0;
}

int compare(const FTSENT** one, const FTSENT** two)
{
    return (strcmp((*one)->fts_name, (*two)->fts_name));
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help.  Apparently I have an issue with over complicating things to the extreme.  There was really no need for me to extrapolate out the path the file was in and the name.  I actually had all the pieces in place, I just broke the problem down too long.  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!

Comment: All other fts examples online produced crazy / random results when used in different environments. For example, in Eclipse, one example caused fts to search my whole system for folders containing files named the same as those found in the folder I actually wanted traversed 0_0

Comment: @Serge likely culprits: symbolic links (junctions, reparse points etc). People assume filesystems are trees... I note that I should probably have explicitly passed `FTS_PHYSICAL` to `fts_open`. Also have a look at `FTS_XDEV` to prevent traversing mountpoints